# Hit highlighting in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have shown a list of people in my site. I am getting the list from my web server.

**My requirement** is to provide a search text box in the application using which user can search the list. Searching the list is easy but I need to highlight the search text in the search result. I don't have to filter list but highlight the search text.

It should look like when we press `ctrl f5` and give a search text.

How to do this?

Answer (score -1):

You need to make a directive that you can pass a block of text. The directive would split the string on whitespace and wrap matches with a `<span>` that you can style to show matches.

Comment: Can you give example?

Comment: @decon: It's pretty self explanatory. I don't see how an example would help. Stack Overflow is a place for finding the information you need to solve the problem, not a copy-paste repository.